# How to fill a shape with the inverse of its background in SVG?

Tags: svg, svg-filters

How to create a shape, e.g. a rectangle, that inverts (xor?) all colors behind it?

Unsuccessfully I tried:

```
<filter
id="invert">
<feColorMatrix
in="BackgroundImage"
values="-1 0 0 0 1 0 -1 0 0 1 0 0 -1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 "/>
<feComposite
operator="in"
in2="SourceGraphic"/>
</filter>
<svg>
  <rect x="10" y="10" width="50" height="50" fill="blue"></rect>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" style="filter: url(#invert);"></rect>
</svg>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bqXPPZ

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BackgroundImage is an unsupported input for almost all browsers and is officially deprecated in the next Filters spec.

Your alternatives are:

- Take a copy of whatever's in the background image and import it into a filter using feImage so you can use it
- Use the non-standard CSS backdrop-filter: invert(100%) - only supported in recent webkit (aka not Chrome)
- Use CSS background-blend and mix-blend (recent browsers only) example:

```css
.content {
  background-image: url("http://stylecampaign.com/blog/blogimages/SVG/fox-1.svg");
  background-size: 600px; 
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 800px;
}

.inverter {
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  mix-blend-mode: exclusion;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="inverter"/>
</div>
```

- Your last option is to layer the original content below the inverted version of your contents using an inversion SVG filter and then use a mask on the inverted version to crop to the desired shape.

```html
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
    <filter id="invert">
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
        <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
        <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="1 0"/>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
    
     <mask id="mask-me">
      <circle cx="215" cy="180" r="100" fill="white" />
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
    <image width="400" height="400" x="20" y="20" xlink:href="http://stylecampaign.com/blog/blogimages/SVG/fox-1.svg" />
  <image width="400" height="400" x="20" y="20" filter="url(#invert)" xlink:href="http://stylecampaign.com/blog/blogimages/SVG/fox-1.svg" mask="url(#mask-me)"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I could not get any of these to work but I am not sure I fully understand them either. It seems, option 1 is out since I am working with a user created svg. I need it to work in at least Firefox as well, so option 2 seems out. For option 3, I have no idea how this is supposed to work. Can you post a working example? Same goes for option 4.

Comment: posted examples

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure yet how to get the inverted color this way. The examples you posted are dependent on some foreground color. However, inversion is independent of it. Maybe I used the wrong term? I meant that I want the background color to be exchanged by its inverse, white <-> black, red <-> cyan, green <-> magenta, blue <-> yellow, etc. Maybe I just have to choose a certain foreground color in your example to get the result? If you have GIMP you can try Colors > Invert. That is the effect I meant.

Comment: Some background: I want to have the shape to be visible independent of the background.

Comment: These do what you want - remember these drawings have transparent black, not white backgrounds. If you paint in a white background, you should get what you want.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. I experimented a bit and could not get it to work. The important thing is that the color of the layer is set to white.

Comment: One catch is that it does not work in IE. So I used a feature detection with a fall-back as a work around: https://jeffclayton.wordpress.com/2015/08/10/1279/.

Comment: If you're comfortable moving entirely to SVG, then the last option above will work in IE 10+

Comment: Thanks. Oh, yes I forgot to mention that I went for the former example. I am actually comfortable to move to SVG entirely but not with duplicating the entire content. The SVG is created on the fly and I am already on the edge performance wise.